# Navigate to View Already in Backstack

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am currently using `MvvmCross` in a `Xamarin.Forms` app.

My situation is this, at a certain point in a user journey, the back stack looks like this

> Root -> View1 -> View2 -> View3

What I need to do, is navigate from View3 back to View1.

I can't just say

```
NavigationService.Navigate<ViewMode1>();
```

As this will simply add it to the back stack, leading to

> Root -> View1 -> View2 -> View3 -> View 1

What I need is

> Root -> View1

I had a look at the documentation and came across

```
NavigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPresentationHint(typeof(ViewModel1)));
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of pages in navigation stack and do like this:

`Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);`

Hope it may solve your issue.